Looking for insulation advice for conditioned sunroom
Current setup is just exposed faced fiberglass that is already falling out and is poorly installed. I am in zone 4, right on the line of zone 3. From looking at a crawlspace ninja video, I had come up with the following plan and just want to see if I'm going the right direction.
-Attach Polyiso to subfloor foil up as vapor barrier and sprayfoam the sides to the Ijoists
-Fill rest of space with r30 unfaced fiberglass
-Attach 1 inch eps foam foil down to bottom of ijoists and tape.
-Screw plywood onto foam to stop critters. Caulk/foam necessary gaps
-Paint
-Add skirting around outside of sunroom to reduce wind from flowing under
-add 6 mil plastic to ground
Thoughts...changes?
